# How to populate table after button click in django template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-templates

1) I want to insert the values in the input field from the dictionary using DTL.
Here's the snippet of code that on load page, making invisible this code  tag in the table (may be because of if condition turns False) but just after data submission from dictionary, showing inserted value in the same  tag.

How can I make it work and remains all the td tags visible on the page load as well?

2) Also since my data.items having 6 keys, so its iterating 6 times, I just want to get single time.

I know I'm not very clear but sorry I can't post the whole code since is too big and confidential.
Please Help it out, I'm totally new in django. Thanks.

```
....
...
..
      {% for key, value in data.items %}
      {% for key2,value2 in value.items %}
      <tr class="info">
        <td>1</td>

        <td>Cholesterol -HDL</td>
        <td>
        {% if value2.test_name == "Cholesterol -HDL" %}
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cholesterol_hdl_result" value="{{ value2.results }}">
        </div>
      </td>
        <td><div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cholesterol_hdl_uom" value="{{ value2.units }}">
        </div></td>
        <td><div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="40.00" name="cholesterol_hdl_lr">
        </div></td>
        <td><div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="60.00" name="cholesterol_hdl_hr">
        </div></td>
        {% endif %}
      </tr>
        {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
..
...
....
```

Comment: It means, on page load you want to get an empty table and when you pass dict on page load you want to fill that table, right?

Comment: Yeah Exactly! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when the dictionary is empty you have to check that in `if` and `else` condition and write that `<td>` tag in else block as below...

```
{% if data %}

    ......
    ......
    {% for key, value in data.items %}
          {% for key2,value2 in value.items %}
              ....
              ....

          {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

{% else %}

    # write your default <td> tag here which is shown when there is empty data dictionary

{% endif %}
```

And for iterate for loop only once you have to use `forloop.first` of django template as below...

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
        {% for key2,value2 in value.items %}
            ....
            ....

        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}  
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Always, Happy coding :)

Comment: Just one more query here, If data.items doesn't contain item checked in the if condition before iteration, It's not providing the input box as well. However, I want the input box as it is. Thanks.

Comment: As per `<td>` tag you can write your `<input>` tags in `else` block. But you have to maintain the `value` attribute of '<input>' tag cz at there you will haven't any dictionary to fill that `value` field. So, you have to make value as empty, might be.

Comment: Hey, @MK Patel !! Can you answer my this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60734026/how-to-append-values-in-a-tabular-format-from-json-in-django-template