# How to append values in a tabular format from JSON in Django Template?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I am making a small web application that allow user to perform OCR on the selected image and provides the JSON output in a tabular Format like this.

[image]

JSON DATA :

```
{
  "data": {
    "test_1": {
      "test_name": "FASTING SUGAR", 
      "results": "121.00", 
      "units": "mg%", 
      "low_range": 70.0, 
      "high_range": 110.0
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm facing now is when I'm selected new image to add values in the table, it overrides the values instead of appending.

And what I want is to append new value in the table by choosing another image, the previous row show me stay as it is and new will get append.

So that finally I can submit all the values to the database all together by clicking on the submit button.

Here is my template code :

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="datatable2" class="table order-column hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Investigation Name</th>
          <th>Result</th>
          <th>UOM</th>
          <th>Low Range</th>
          <th>High Range</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for key, value in data.items %}
        {% for key2,value2 in value.items %}
        <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>{{ value2.test_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ value2.results }}</td>
        <td>{{ value2.units }}</td>
        <td>{{ value2.low_range }}</td>
        <td>{{ value2.high_range }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<!--end .table-responsive -->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="data">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import json
import urllib.request
from .models import Panel
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import PanelForm, SingleDataForm

def photo_single(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = PanelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form1 = SingleDataForm()
        if form.is_valid():
            print("valid")
            temp,data = form.save()
            return render(request, 'album/photo_single.html', {'data': data, 'form1':form1, 'form': form})
            #return redirect('photo_list')
    else:
        form = PanelForm()

    if request.method=='POST' and 'data' in request.POST:
        form1 = SingleDataForm(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid():
            print("INside this loop")
            if form1.save():
                print("INside this loop")
                return redirect('album/photo_single.html', messages.success(request, 'Order was successfully created.', 'alert-success'))
            else:
                return redirect('album/photo_single.html', messages.error(request, 'Data is not saved', 'alert-danger'))
        else:
            return redirect('album/photo_single.html', messages.error(request, 'Form is not valid', 'alert-danger'))
    else:
        form1 = SingleDataForm()
    return render(request, 'album/photo_single.html', {'form': form, 'form1':form1})
```

How can we use list in DTL to store the previous values and stay as it is and the new value just get append in the next row.. ?
I'm new in Django. Please Guide. Thanks.

Comment: It mean when you choose file and submit the form then page will be reload and you want to append the new data with existing also, right?

Comment: Exactly. I want the new data to be added in the next row and so on. And when I hit submit, all the data with be save in the database.

Comment: Then why you are getting only last sbmitted data when you reload the page? I think you have to fetch all the required data from database when reload the page and pass that data from view to html and iterate it in html page.

Comment: And also provide your `views.py` so, I can more understand it.

Comment: I simply performing OCR on Image with API. I'm sending image to the API and it is returning back with the OCR output in the JSON format. Before submitting to the database, I'm trying it on show on the table and by hitting submit, all the values would get submit in the database. I think we need to use variable to store the output of the first JSON data, then have to append it with the newer one.

Comment: Ok, let me check

Comment: Sure! Please. let me know. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209909/discussion-between-mk-patel-and-sodmzs).